# Idiomatic slice splice in Go?

Tags: go

I have the following code for implementing a splice (that is, given a byte slice full, another byte slice part, and an int pos representing the position in full that I want to overwrite with part):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    full := []byte{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    part := []byte{1,1,1}

    newFull1 := splice(full, part, 2)
    fmt.Println(newFull1)
    // [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]

    newFull2 := splice(full, part, 3)
    fmt.Println(newFull2)
    // [0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
}

func splice(full []byte, part []byte, pos int) []byte {
    return bytes.Join([][]byte{full[:pos], part, full[len(full[:pos])+len(part):]}, []byte{})
}
```

Basically, my method does a join of 3 byte slices: the first part of full that doesn't get overwritten by part, all of part, and then the remaining part of full. Is there a better/more idiomatic way of doing this? I wasn't able to find a method that implemented this in the standard library.

Comment: Looks good to me.  I don't think you'll find a more succinct was to accomplish this.  You might want to add error checking though.  pos can potentially be out of bounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know part is completely within the bounds of full, you can use the copy function.

```
func main() {
    full := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    part := []byte{1, 1, 1}

    copy(full[2:], part)
    fmt.Println(full)
}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/toFIvcYFW-)

That overwrites full though.  If you wanted to preserve the original, you could make a copy first with the append function.

```
func main() {
    full := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    part := []byte{1, 1, 1}

    newFull := append([]byte{}, full...)
    copy(newFull[2:], part)
    fmt.Println("newFull:      ", newFull)
    fmt.Println("original full:", full)
}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xrqJwz5Pvj)

Note that this still has the limitation of your original code that part must fit within the bounds of full.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `append` built-in?

```
func splice(full, part []byte, pos int) (ret []byte) {
    ret = append(full[:pos], part...)
    return append(ret, full[pos:]...)
}
```

This may not be very fast (lots of copying), but it's pretty readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant for splicing byte slices. The algorithm is similar to Anton Litvinov's stringSplice(). Because the append function shares the same slice as the input, a copy of the same length as the input must be used. This was not done by 'beatgammit' in the previous answer, which does not work correctly.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sliceSplice(input []byte, start, deleteCount int, item []byte) ([]byte) {
    fmt.Printf("input:      %v start = %d deleteCount = %d item: %v\n", input, start, deleteCount, item)
    cpy := make([]byte, len(input))
    copy(cpy, input)
    fmt.Println("cpy:       ", cpy)
    if start > len(cpy) {
        return append(cpy, item...)
    }
    ret := append(cpy[:start], item...)
    fmt.Println("ret:       ", ret)

    if start+deleteCount > len(cpy) {
        return ret
    }
    fmt.Println("cpy:       ", cpy, "       modified by shared slice 'ret'")
    fmt.Println("input[s+d] ", input[start+deleteCount:], "         not modified")
    return append(ret, input[start+deleteCount:]...)
}

func main() {
    oldFull := []byte{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
    fmt.Println("oldFull:      ", oldFull, "\n")
    myFull := sliceSplice(oldFull, 3, 0, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
    myFull = sliceSplice(oldFull, 3, 1, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
    myFull = sliceSplice(oldFull, 3, 4, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
    myFull = sliceSplice(oldFull, 3, 6, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
    myFull = sliceSplice(oldFull, 7, 0, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
    myFull = sliceSplice(oldFull, 9, 6, []byte{2, 2})
    fmt.Println("myFull:       ", myFull, "\n")
}
```

I have also included a group of test cases

Answer (score 0):

A variant for string (split / splice / join).

```
func stringSplice(full string, start, deleteCount int, item string) (ret string) {
    if start > len(full) {
        return full + item
    }
    ret = full[:start] + item

    if start+deleteCount > len(full) {
        return ret
    }
    return ret + full[start+deleteCount:]
}
```