# Idiomatic Splice in Go

Tags: for-loop, go, slice

I checked an existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544374/idiomatic-slice-splice-in-go) but it's not similar to my case.

I need to pluck an element at the index and break out of the `for` loop at runtime based on `Compare` function.

Issues:
If element to pluck is found at `0` `index`, `index-1` will throw slice bounds of range error and similarly if `index+1` is greater than `len(elements)`.

Question: What's the best concise way to achieve the above?

```
for index, element := range elements {
    if element.Compare() == true {
        elements = append(elements[:index-1], elements[index+1:]...)
        break
    }
}
```

**Attempt**

```
for index, element := range elements {
    if element.Compare() == true {
        if len(elements) > 1 {
            elements = append(elements[:index-1], elements[index+1:]...)
        } else if len(elements) == 1 {
            delete(elements, 0)
        }
        break
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2**  [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XzMircxnKP) any improvements/suggestions?

The idea is to copy the remaining elements from beginning to index and then any elements after.

```
var elements = []string {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
fmt.Println(elements)
for index, element := range elements {
    if element == "c" {
        var temp = elements[:index]
        for i := index + 1; i<len(elements); i++ {
            temp = append(temp, elements[i])
        }
        elements = temp
        break
    }
}
fmt.Println(elements)
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: what's the best way to pluck an element from slice

Comment: Are you attempting to remove a single element? The one being at index `index`?

Comment: yes single element only and breaking after that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The high index in a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) is **exclusive**.

This means your example is flawed, and also that no special treatment is required.

The correct slicing expression is:

```
elements = append(elements[:index], elements[index+1:]...)
```

If `index` is the first element (`0`), then `elements[:0]` will be an empty slice.

If `index` is the last element (`len-1`), then `elements[index+1:]` will also be an empty slice, as `index+1` will be equal to the lenght of the slice. So the solution is simply:

```
for index, element := range elements {
    if element.Compare() {
        elements = append(elements[:index], elements[index+1:]...)
        break
    }
}
```

To demonstrate it on the Go Playground, let's substitute the `Compare()` method with a simple index check:

```
for _, idxToRemove := range []int{0, 2, 4} {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    for i := range s {
        if i == idxToRemove {
            s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(idxToRemove, ":", s)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hA8J-cTsVg)):

```
0 : [1 2 3 4]
2 : [0 1 3 4]
4 : [0 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the slice `s` is sorted and `len(s)` is large, find `x` using a binary search. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func pluck(s []string, x string) []string {
    i := sort.SearchStrings(s, x)
    if i >= 0 && i < len(s) && s[i] == x {
        s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...)
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = pluck(s, "b")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[a b c d]
[a c d]
```

If the order of slice `s` does not need to be preserved, switch elements. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func pluck(s []string, x string) []string {
    for i, v := range s {
        if v == x {
            s[i] = s[len(s)-1]
            s = s[:len(s)-1]
            break
        }
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = pluck(s, "b")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[a b c d]
[a d c]
```

Otherwise, splice slice `s` elements. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func pluck(s []string, x string) []string {
    for i, v := range s {
        if v == x {
            s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = pluck(s, "b")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
[a b c d]
[a c d]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is idiomatic, but this works quite well:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func splice(start, count int, items []string) (ret []string) {
    ret = make([]string, len(items)-count)
    copy(ret, items[:start])
    copy(ret[start:], items[start+count:])
    return
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = splice(1, 2, s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UNtdtw77sEQ